# Exclude certain columns from SHOW COLUMNS mysql

Tags: php, mysql, select, while-loop

I have this query: `SHOW COLUMNS FROM mash` which works fine in my while loop for building a select element made from table column names. But in my table i have "id" and "tstamp" which i dont want in the select element, is this possible to exclude these columns?

```
echo "<form action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."' method='get'>";
            connectDB();
            $result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM mash") or die(mysql_error());
            echo '<select name="column" class="column">';
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo "<option value='".$row[0]."'>".ucwords($row[0])."</option>";
            }
            closeConn();
            echo '</select>';
echo "</form>";
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### PHP Way:

Use a [`continue`](http://php.net/continue) in the while loop, when those fields are fetched, like this:

```
echo "<form action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."' method='get'>";
    connectDB();
    $result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM mash") or die(mysql_error());
    echo '<select name="column" class="column">';
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        if($row[0] == 'id' || $row[0] == 'tstamp')
              continue;
        echo "<option value='".$row[0]."'>".ucwords($row[0])."</option>";
    }
    closeConn();
    echo '</select>';
echo "</form>";
```

This will just skip the `id` and `tstamp` fields and process all others. `continue` is used within looping structures to skip the rest of the current loop iteration and continue execution at the condition evaluation and then the beginning of the next iteration.

---

### MySQL Way:

Remove those fields in the query like this:

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM mash WHERE Field NOT IN ('id', 'tstamp');
```

Comment: @benhowdle89: http://uk.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php - it skips the rest of the current iteration of the loop (in this case, it would go to the while($row...)). The Fine Manual does have useful information, most of the time.

Comment: @benhowdle89, I have edited answer to show what continue means.

Comment: thanks Shamittomar, very detailed response, i will bear "continue" in mind for the future!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible. Instead of using `SHOW COLUMNS` use [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html).

`INFORMATION_SCHEMA` is the ANSI way of extracting metadata from a relational database. In MySQL you can use:

```
$sql = "select column_name from information_schema.columns c " + 
       " where c.table_schema = 'db_name' " + 
       "   and c.table_name='table_name' " + 
       "   and c.column_name like 'name%'";
```

Information Schema has the advantage that is SQLANSI compliant. You can use it in MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLServer and other relational databases.

Answer (score 2):

You can use LIKE operator.

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM mash LIKE "name%"
```

Answer (score 0):

To see just the "Collation" column that shows up in `SHOW FULL COLUMNS from tablename` for just one field, it's:

```
select COLLATION_NAME from information_schema.columns
where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'tableschemaname' and TABLE_NAME = 'tablename' and COLUMN_NAME = 'fieldname';
```

Ddrop the `fieldname` in the `where`, if you want to see that column for all field names.

To see all possible column names that show up from `SHOW FULL COLUMNS` so that you can select what you want:

```
select * from information_schema.columns 
where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'tableschemaname' and TABLE_NAME = 'tablename' and COLUMN_NAME = 'fieldname';
```